# Library to send SMS from proper phone

Tags: jar, sms, at-command

it's a couple of day I'm searching this library:
com.siemens.icm.io.ATCommand
http://gsmpager.spb.ru/doc/tc65wtkr3/com/siemens/icm/io/ATCommand.html

I found the documentation but not the jar.
Can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you won't find this JAR standalone, it is built into Siemens/Cinterion TC65 modules and is device specific.